# Pig latin string conversion in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that turns text into pig Latin: simple text transformation that modifies each word moving the first character to the end and appending "ay" to the end. But all I get is an empty list. Any tips?

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    endString = str(word[1]).upper()+str(word[2:])
    them = endString, str(word[0:1]).lower(), 'ay'
    word = ''.join(them)
    return word

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Comment: Do you want to return word instead of words?  It might break anyway

Comment: Why do you split `say` instead of `text`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If I return word I get an error:
Error on line 13:
    print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
Error on line 11:
    return word
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word' referenced before assignment

Comment: As it seems to me, you are probably splitting the wrong string in the third line. Isn't it that you intend to split string-variable 'text' into 'words', instead of the kinda empty string 'say'?

Comment: @emremrah because say is the string I want to split isn't it? If I split text I get:
you
fun

Comment: Yes @DanielB. that is right. But don't I need an empty string to assign to any text?

Comment: No, actually `text` is the string that you want to split. `say` is just an empty string, and you are not adding it any string in the following lines of code, so it remains empty. Please check out my answer, you will see it.

Comment: Depends on the concrete implementation, but in most cases that is correct. However, what you are essentially trying to do in the code fragment is to split a pretty empty string, and hence not the one you really  intend to split. As I see it, you want to iterate over the individual words contained in the input string passed to your function 'pig_latin'. But that input string is contained in your input variable 'text'. Hence, you have to split the text sequence contained in the 'text' string-variable [by applying the .split() method to it] into 'words'.

Comment: Actually my answer is nearly identical as @ventaquil, I didn't noticed that. Since he/she answered first, you can select his/her answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: "don't I need an empty string to assign to any text?" I don't think I understand what this is intended to mean, but I think you must be confused about how names work in Python. There is no such thing as initializing a variable in Python; the first time you assign is basically the same as any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
def pig_latin(text):
  words = text.split()
  pigged_text = []

  for word in words:
    word = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
    pigged_text.append(word)

  return ' '.join(pigged_text)

print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))
```

Outputs: `ellohay owhay reaay ouyay`

Comment: Actually my answer is nearly identical as @ventaquil, I didn't noticed that. Since he/she answered first, you can select his/her answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried this and it worked for me**

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = []

  # Separate the text into words

  words = text.split()
  for word in words:

    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list

    word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    say.append(word)

    # Turn the list back into a phrase

  return " ".join(say)

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"

print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

**Open for suggestions**

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a list comprehension for compactness and simplicity:

`’ ‘.join([word[1:] + word[0] + ‘ay’ for word in text.split(‘ ‘)])`

Answer (score 1):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = []
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split(" ")
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    say.append(word[1:]+word[0]+'ay')
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return " ".join(x for x in say)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```py
def pig_latin(sentence):
    output = []
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        output.append(word)
    return " ".join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension on each word then join it back together.

edit:  this solution have issues with multiple spaces, like when people put two spaces after a `colon:  !`

```
def dowork(sentence):

    def pigword(word):
        return "".join([word[1:], word[0], "ay"])

    return " ".join([pigword(word) for word in sentence.split()])


dataexp = [
    ("hello how are you","ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"),
    ("programming in python is fun","rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay")
    ]

for inp, exp in dataexp:
    got = dowork(inp)
    msg = "exp :%s:  for %s \n      got :%s:" % (exp, inp, got)
    if exp == got:
        print("good! %s" % msg)
    else:
        print("bad ! %s" % msg)
```

#### output

```
good! exp :ellohay owhay reaay ouyay:  for hello how are you
      got :ellohay owhay reaay ouyay:
good! exp :rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay:  for programming in python is fun
      got :rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay:
```

Comment: Why would you need a nested function?  ' '.join([x[1:]+x[0]+'ay' for x in 'hello world'.split()])

Comment: well, it doesn't have to be nested.  but I like making it into its own function to separate concerns.  to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked in my case:

```
   def pig_latin(text):
      # Separate the text into words
        words = text.split()
        #creating a new empty list called pig
        pig=[]
        # creating a for loop to alter every word in words
        for word in words:
            
            """here we are assigning the altered word to a new variable pigged_word. The we can remove first word alone from the original word usin
                indexing and add/concat the letter at zeroth index (1st letter) back to the
                    word and add/concat new string 'ay' at end """
            
            pigged_word=word[1:]+word[0]+'ay'
            #append the altered words to the list
            # use append instead of insert since you can add word to end of list
            pig.append(pigged_word)
            #now convert it back to 
        return (' '.join(pig))
            
    print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
    print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Kindly try to understand the question and solve. Splitting the say variable won't work , ideally you'll have to split the text into pieces and even then you don't have to split with `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Herman Singh's answer, but omitting the anti-pattern (might be a bit strong to call it that) of creating an empty list and appending to it in a for-loop.

```
def pig_latin(text):
    words = [
        word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        for word in text.split()
    ]
    return " ".join(words)


print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))  # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun"))  # Should be "rogrammingpay n
```

Which can be reduced to a single line, but I think it doesn't aid readability.

```
def pig_latin(text):
    return " ".join([word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" for word in text.split()])


print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))  # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun"))  # Should be "rogrammingpay siay unfay
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def pig_latin(text):
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  newWord = []
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    n = ""
    for char in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
      if(char == 0) :
        n+= (word[char]+"ay")
      n += word[char]
    newWord.append(n)    
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return " ".join(newWord)
    
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

def pig_latin(text):

```
say = ""
  pig_list= []
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split(' ')
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    # print(word)
    pig_list.append(word)
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
    say = ' '.join(pig_list)
  return say
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `.join` and `.append`:

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    pig_word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay "
    say += pig_word
  return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    say += word[1:] + word[0] + "ay "
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say.rstrip(" ")

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = ""
    str=[]
  # Separate the text into words
    words = text.split()
   for word in words:
     # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
      say=word[1:]+word[:1]+"ay"
      str.append(say)
      # Turn the list back into a phrase
      joined=" ".join(str)
      return joined
    
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay 
ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    say = say + word[1:] +word[0] +"ay "
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return "".join(say)

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = " "
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the   list
    say+=word[1:]+word[0]+str("ay")+ " "
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say
    
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    word = str(word[1])+str(word[2:] + str(word[0:1]).lower() + 'ay')
    say = say + word + " "
  return say

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) 
# Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun"))
 # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = "ay"
    # Separate the text into words
    words = text.split()
    newtext = []
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    for newword in words:
        newlist = newword[1:] + newword[0] + say
        newtext.append(newlist)
    return " ".join(newtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  last = words[-1]
  for word in words:
    if word == last:
        say += word[1:]+word[0]+"ay"
    else:
         say += word[1:]+word[0]+"ay "
  return say

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Will get the output without that extra space at end of sentence.

Comment: I attempted to do it without altering the given codes in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is better work I think so as it is simple to understand

```
def pig_latin(text):
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  list1 = []
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    pig_latin = word[0] + "ay"
    mod_word = word.replace(word[0],"")
    mod_word2 = mod_word + pig_latin
    list1.append(mod_word2)
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return " ".join(list1)
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    word=word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" + " "
    say +=word
  return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may solve the OP's issues, it's recommended to provide an explanation about the written code to make your answer more understandable for the community and also to improve its quality

Answer (score -1):

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    say += " {}{}ay".format(word[1:], word[0])
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say
    
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the following code:

```
def pig_latin(texts):
    return ' '.join([text.replace(text[0],'') + text[0]+'ay' for text in texts.split()])

print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun"))
```

will get the desired result:

```
ellohay owhay reaay ouyay
rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay
```

Comment: Your code style is called list comprehensive and its works BUT it adds unwanted space to the end of each line it outputs which need to be rectified. :)